# What is a good wordpress Gallery plugin with a customizable lightbox?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, elementor

I want a plugin that allows me to create a wordpress gallery:

1. The thumbnails should display the image's caption/title
2. The lightbox should display a description text. (If possible, a link/button to a contact page also).

I have explored a lot of gallery plugins but almost all have pretty basic lightboxes. I prefer not to meddle with code too much. Looking for a customizable plugin instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a very Good Plugin. WordPress NextGEN Gallery Plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to add it to a page?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a gallery with shortcode.